# Removing Transmission Bit torrent client

Tags: 13.04, bittorrent, transmission

Simply want to remove this client, don't really like it.  Can't figure out what packages it's installed as, tried both transmission and transmission-daemon, the first not being anything and the second states it's not installed.

Running ubuntu 13.04, all updated.

Just don't like having programs I don't use/want to use deluge.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The package name is transmission-gtk, so:

```
sudo apt-get purge transmission-gtk
```

Comment: I test this and not work, it said: `Package 'transmission-gtk' is not installed, so not removed`

Answer (score 10):

Try this. It should work.

```
sudo apt-get purge transmission-cli transmission-common transmission-daemon
```

Comment: Why would this answer be better than the current existing one?

Comment: Care to explain what this command will do?

Comment: Frankly this work, but still not remove the web page version.

Answer (score 5):

To remove everything to do with transmission, use:

```
sudo apt-get purge transmission*
```

This will remove every package with the word transmission followed by any number of letters.

Comment: In newer versions (at least definitely in 16.04) it is no longer the case.

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then type in :

`sudo apt-get remove transmission-gtk`

This will remove the transmission bittorent client. After this process has completed, you type in the open terminal "

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

This command will remove all the dependencies associated with the app you would've just removed, as well as some other unwanted dependencies and files related to uninstalled app. This will keep your system clean and running smoothly and avoid resource wastage.

Answer (score 3):

In the Dash, search for Transmission as you normally would to launch it. Right-click and you'll see a screen about Transmission; one of the buttons on that screen is `Uninstall`. This works for any app you would like to remove.

Answer (score 3):

Complete and clean remove (for non GTK) in 4 steps:

```
sudo apt-get remove transmission-cli transmission-common transmission-daemon
sudo apt-get purge transmission-cli transmission-common transmission-daemon
```

Optionally:

```
sudo rm -fr /etc/transmission-daemon/
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove transmission-cli transmission-common transmission-daemon
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three steps you need to follow to remove altogether transmission from the system

1. `sudo apt-get purge transmission*`
2. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/transmission-*`
3. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/applications/transmission-gtk.desktop`